# Trac plugin to send email number of new and closed tickets and their details based on define schedule

Tags: trac

I am looking for a way or a plugin so that trac sends me **email** about the **number of new or closed tickets** (and some information about these tickets also ) **for a specific duration** lets say for the last three days.

Basically I need to know how many tickets have been created in last week and how many of them have been closed at the end of week.

Of course the email only should be sent to the admin and not to all the users.

Answer (score 1):

For additional Trac funcionality we have Trac plugins, yes. And the first place to look for them is [trac-hacks.org](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/) .

The excellent TagsPlugin in use overthere already delivers some hints on resources tagged with [notification](http://trac-hacks.org/tags/%27notification%27) or [notifications](http://trac-hacks.org/tags/%27notifications%27). The most comprehensive and mature solution is certainly [TracAnnouncer](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AnnouncerPlugin) with a just reworked configuration interface providing a highly sophisticated opt-in and opt-out subscription system. Unfortunately digest notification are not integrated today.

Still there are other plugins, that fill in the gap, i.e. check the [XMailPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/MailPlugin). It claims to do configurable instant, daily and weekly notifications, so this may be for you. Since this is a relativly new plugin, you should expect some pending issues, but the author might be very open to your suggestion. If you're becoming a heavy user giving valuable test feedback and a bit lucky too, asking kindly could be enought to make things happen.

Answer (score 0):

There's a slightly different way to solve this problem that doesn't require any plugins.  First, create a custom "timeline" view that displays the information that you want.  In your example, this would be all "opened and closed tickets" starting from "today" and going back three days.  When viewing this custom view, you should see a link at the bottom of the page that says "RSS Feed" (on my system, the resulting URL looks something like this: `http://myserver/timeline?ticket=on&max=50&authors=&daysback=3&format=rss`).  Click on this link to subscribe to the feed using your web browser, email client, or other program capable of reading feeds.  Now, you can view the results live at any time.  What you can do at this point is only limited by the capabilities of your feed reader app, but most can at least be configured to notify you when the feed is updated.